# Is ILogger an unstructured logging/normal logging? What's the difference with normal logging and structured logging

Tags: c#, .net, logging

I'm new to log in adding it to programs. I do use it but wanted some answers. Is ILogger an unstructured logging/normal logging? What's the difference with normal logging and structured logging?

I want to find out the differences and have structured logging for my programs.

Comment: ILogger is just an interface, it doesn't have any bearing on whether you're doing structured vs unstructured logging. It sounds like you don't know what structured logging is, because if you did you'd be able to recognize it when you see it. I suggest you read through [Nick Blumhardt's series on the topic](https://nblumhardt.com/2016/06/structured-logging-concepts-in-net-series-1/). He's the creator of Serilog, a popular library for doing structured logging in .NET.

Comment: Hi @mason, Yes will do that. Just a quick question, the log which I use from this library Microsoft.Extensions.Logging, is this unstructured?

Comment: It depends on how you use it.

Comment: @PPPP the very first comment explained this is just the interface. It doesn't log anything anywhere. It's the logging providers/sinks that actually write stuff. If you use Serilog you'll get structured logs. If you use some other flat file log sink, you'll get flat files.

Comment: @PPPP feel free to [accept any answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it was of any help to you. If it isn't, feel free to ask for details.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the `Ilogger` interface supports both structured and unstructured logging. Of course how it is implemented depends on the actual logger that is used in the application.

The Microsoft documentation uses `Log message template` as the term for structured logging as shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#log-message-template). The same doc described the advantage like this:

> This approach allows logging providers to implement semantic or structured logging. The arguments themselves are passed to the logging system, not just the formatted message template. This enables logging providers to store the parameter values as fields.

The docs link to [this post](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-use-structured-logging) for more details.

In short, the main benefit is that when you examine the generated logs you can find specific log entries by filtering on actual properties instead of having to parse the log message using for example regex to find specific log entries.